# CSS positioning issue in IE 8

Tags: html, css, alignment, positioning

I am facing an positioning related issue in the template (on Footer Wrapper), specifically in IE8 (works fine in most of the browsers, including the IE8 mode in IE 9 and 10).

[image]

where it is supposed to appear like :

[image]

The associated CSS is :
[image]

Any kind of suggestions would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try these links to fix any Internet Explorer issues:

(download respond.min.js) https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond

(download css3-mediaqueries.js) https://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/

Add this to your `<head>` tag after you download:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="respond.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual html code would help, but I guess you could solve it with a

```
<br clear="all" />
```

after your floated divs

Or by setting the div that contains the floated elements to

```
height:100%;
```

Hope this helps !